# Replit + Pandas --> pd.read_csv --> Unexpected outputs

Tags: pandas

I want to gather all rows with a value of 'male' in the column 'sex' and get the 'age'. I tried several ways but still struggle:

```
import pandas as pd
def calculate_demographic_data(print_data=True):
    # Read data from file
    df = pd.read_csv('adult.data.csv')
# 1. try
    print(df[df['sex']=='male']['age'])
# 2. try
    print(df.loc[df['sex'] == 'male']['age'])
```

1. prints:
   ESeries([], Name: age, dtype: int64)
2. prints:
   ESeries([], Name: age, dtype: int64)

Someone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

On the second try, you forgot a `'` at the end. :)

Comment: I saw that you added the `'`. I assume that it still doesn't work. Could you comment the output of `df.head(10)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path to the csv file, so on replit is something like

`~/Your-Project-Name/adult.data.csv`